# Nested alert messages in Xamarin iOS using UIAlertController

Tags: c#, ios8, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uialertcontroller

Trying to create a nested dialogues in Xamarin iOS - idea is to show detailed exception information. I'm new to iOS development. I'd like to know if I'm on the right path to begin with? And what am I missing?

In the example below when user clicks `ShowDetailedException` additional popup dialogue should appear

```
----------------------
|Error               | 
|Something went wrong|          
|____________________|
|ShowDetailedException|Ok|

-----------------------
|Title                |
|Exception(StackTrace)|
-----------------------
|OK button            |
-----------------------
```

I'm trying to implement this in `UIViewController` class. 
What I have so far:

```
     public void ShowErrorMessage(Exception ex)   
     {
            bool isDebug;
#if DEBUG

            isDebug = true;
#endif
            var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Error", "Something went wrong", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
            if (isDebug)
            {
                var infoAction = UIAlertAction.Create("Info", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => ShowError(ex));

                alert.AddAction(infoAction);                                    
            }    
            SetupPopover(alert, this.View);
            this.PresentViewController(alert, animated: true, completionHandler: null);
        }

 private void SetupPopover(UIAlertController alertController, UIView sourceView)
        {
            var popover = alertController.PopoverPresentationController;
            if (popover != null)
            {
                popover.SourceView = sourceView;
                popover.SourceRect = sourceView.Bounds;
            }
        }
```

I've managed to implement this using `UIAlertView` but since iOS 8 uses `UIAlertController`, I have to use that.

Currently my `alert.PopoverPresentationController` is null...

Any help and ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`alertController.PopoverPresentationController` will only return an instance if it's running on an iPad or IPhone 6+ (I think).  If it's running on a compact device, like the phones, NULL will be returned.

If you say you having it working with `UIAlertView`, then it should still execute on iOS 8.

Comment: Thanks for this, but my requirement is to use `UIAlertController`